# Elastic search - match phrase query on copy_to field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to fix some multi term search, specifically when searching something like:

"This awesome excursion" to resolve when a user types: "This awesom". Managed to get it to work with a match_phrase_query, instead of it previously using a query_string query.

Now though this breaks searching on compound fields. For finding users in the system I created a copy_to field, for things like salutation, first name, middle name and last name to populate. So it looks like this:

```
"contact": {
    "properties": {
        "contact_full_name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "first_name": {
            "copy_to": "contact_full_name",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort",
                    "ignore_above": 10922,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "string"
        },
        "last_name": {
            "copy_to": "contact_full_name",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort",
                    "ignore_above": 10922,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
        },
        "middle_name": {
            "copy_to": "contact_full_name",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort",
                    "ignore_above": 10922,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "string"
        },
        "salutation": {
            "copy_to": "contact_full_name",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort",
                    "ignore_above": 10922,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I then post the following query:

```
{
    "fields": "id",
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "minimum_should_match": "1",
                    "must_not": {
                        "term": {
                            "deleted": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "should": {
                        "match": {
                            "contact_full_name": {
                                "query": "John G",
                                "type": "phrase_prefix"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 50
}
```

And i get no results. If I use "John" as the term, it returns the result fine. I have a feeling it has to do with what order the fields are copied. Is there a way for me to work around this, or do I need to use an alternate search to make this work?

The values stored:

- first name: John
- last name: Smith
- middle name: Glenn
- salutation: Mr

Comment: Hi ! I admit that the post is now dead but I am having the exact same issue. Did you find any solution (beside indexing the contact_full_name directly) ?

Comment: @maxime Sorry I honestly don't remember. I no longer have this project code around to reference either. I have a feeling I moved away from phrase_prefix to another type of query.

Comment: Since I am not sure, I will not post a real answer to this question but after investigation, I found that "copy_to" does not concatenate the tokens in order but instead create a set of tokens (loosing the order in the process) making it impossible to use with "phrase like" queries or any queries that is dependent on the token order. Knowing that, it became obvious that _source transformation is the way to go (in other words, I simply create a full_name field that I set during the indexation process).